# Visual studio 2017 Xamarin Build access denied on obj folder

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to build an App but when I try to build, I get access denied errors.

When I restart my computer, I have access to the Obj folders in my projects in the solution.
I can remove them without problems.

After I start up Visual Studio 2017, without any project, I still have access to those folders.

Then I load my solution (3 projects) and the Obj folders in those projects are not accessible anymore. I get the message from windows (10 pro) that I need administrators rights, which I have, when I want to access the folders.
I get a message about not being "builtin\administrator" and so not allowed to access.

Closing Visual studio does not resolve this.
I have to restart my computer to get access to those folders again.

I didn't have this problem yesterday, I got some windows update this morning.

Is there a way to resolve this as I cannot build my app now since it wants to copy a file to that folder?

Edit:
Rebooted my computer, deleted all BIN and OBJ folders from the solutions projects, set the access rights for all users to full control on the parent of the parent of the solution folder and then started Visual studio as administrator and opened the solution.
No change, still no access during build or via windows explorer.

[image: Error message in Visual Studio]

[image: Windows explorer permissions]

[image: Delete fail]

A colleque of mine was able to reproduce the problem by creating a new project and updating Visual Studio 2017 and windows (10 pro) to the latest version .

Comment: try rebooting the computer and deleting the obj folder.  It will be recreated.

Comment: That I did, but then the problem returns

Comment: Maybe permissions of parent folder are already damaged. Make sure there is an entry for "Users" that gives *full access* and is applied to "this folder, sub folders and files".

Comment: @zett42: see edit

Comment: Even if you have no permissions, you can always take ownership (provided your account has admin privileges). Make sure to select the checkbox to take ownership of all sub folders too. After that you should be able to fix the permissions.

Comment: @zett42: tried that, no change.

Comment: try [this tool to take ownership](https://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.18)

Comment: It doesn't really matter if I take ownership. Visual Studio locks itself out for access. That is why the build is failing.

Comment: Problem was solved. It was cause by a anti-virus app. Changed it to another one and the problem was gone.

Comment: @Eric post your solution (anti-virus) as an answer and accept that answer if it truly DID resolve it for you! Good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved. It was cause by a anti-virus app. Changed it to another one and the problem was gone.

Comment: I had the same problem. It was not caused by an anti-virus app.

I "unlocked" the folder with IOBit Unlocker and then deleted it. Everything now seems fine.

I assumed that the MacBook which is connected to my Windows VS2019 PC for Xamarin iOS development, was creating the file. But, this is a wild assumption based on no real knowledge of how it all works.